# Javascript/YUI Character Counter off by one

Tags: javascript, yui, charactercount

I've gone over the code several times and can't figure out why the first keystroke doesn't seem to count.

When the textarea is an empty string, the counter display should read accurately. But it seems that the textarea needs to be empty twice.......

http://jsfiddle.net/ndreckshage/zVQZR/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try listening to the `keyup` event instead.

The `keypress` event is fired when the actual character is **being inserted** in the textarea. When you read the value of the textarea — `message.get('value')`, the old value **before** the `keypress` event is returned. This explains why the counter shows an outdated (inaccurate) number of characters left.

More about `keydown`, `keypress`, and `keyup` events: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html

---

**UPDATE:**

There is a better way to detect changes to `<input>` and `<textarea>`.

The YUI `event-valuechange` module provides a [`valuechange` event](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/valuechange.html) that fires when the user changes the input value by:

- typing a simple character
- typing a multi-stroke character
- using an Input Method Editor
- cutting from or pasting into the value with Ctrl+X or Cmd+V
- cutting or pasting with a keyboard-summoned context menu; or
- cutting or pasting from the right-click context menu.

Here's how to use it on an input with ID `message`:

```js
YUI().use('event-valuechange', function (Y) {
    Y.one('#message').on('valueChange', function (e) {
        // The value has changed! Handle it here...
    });
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Pd9X9/

Comment: this was very helpful and worked correctly. thank you. thanks for the link as well

Comment: BTW, im adding more events based on the link you provided to make this work a bit better. however, on paste does not seem to work. any idea why not? -----Y.on('keyup', updateCharCount, '#message');
Y.on('mouseup', updateCharCount, '#message');
Y.on('blur', updateCharCount, '#message');
Y.on('paste', updateCharCount, '#message');

Comment: The `paste` event doesn't work because it's not one of the [whitelisted DOM events](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/#event-whitelist). Also, the `paste` event itself isn't too reliable to start with ([read more](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/cutcopypaste.html)). I've updated my answer with a better solution using YUI's `valuechange` event.

Answer (score 1):

Change to the `keyup` event and it works fine for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/grZW7/.  The keypress event only happens on some keys and may happen BEFORE the text of the field is updated whereas `keyup` always happens afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'keyup' as the event trigger

Comment: This is not a good answer - either leave it as a comment or include an explanation of why `keyup` is the appropriate trigger.

Comment: Will do. I'm a newbie here. Thanks for the positive feedback.